# For $1-w\bar w$ is positive definite , there exists an $n × n$ matrix $a$ with complex entries such that $(1- w\bar w)\{a\}= 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-forms

For $1-w\bar w$  is positive definite , there exists an $n × n$ matrix $a$ with complex entries such that $(1- w\bar w)\{a\}= 1$ where $1$ in the identity matrix and $w$ is $ n$ rowed complex symmetric matrix. Where $ a\{b\}=\bar b^t a b$ .
How to prove this as I know that all the eigen values are real and positive. Does this imply anything else? please help.

Comment: If $X$ is symmetric and has orthogonal eigenvectors $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ with positive eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ then write $V$ for the matrix whose columns are the $v_i$s and figure out what $V^{\ast}XV$ must be. (Answer: diagonal matrix. Which is similar to the identity matrix.)

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues. What do you know about the determinant of your matrix and what does that say about whether or not it has an inverse?

Comment: @user1551 why that is true? If the matrix $A$ commutes with the orthogonal matrix which takes the matrix $P$ to its diagonal form then it would hold I think. Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: @anon if $X$ is symmetric then the result is true I know but here $1-w \bar w$ is Hermitian. Does it hold for Hermitian as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the property that $w$ is complex symmetric. For any Hermitian matrix $P$, if there exists a square matrix $A$ such that $A^\ast PA=I$, then $P=(AA^\ast)^{-1}$, which is positive definite. Conversely, if $P$ is positive definite, by taking $A=P^{-1/2}$, we have $A^\ast PA=I$.

Comment: What $P^{-1/2}$?

Comment: @user152715 $P^{1/2}$ denotes the unique positive definite square root of $P$, and $P^{-1/2}$ is the inverse of $P^{1/2}$.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks. It was pretty easy. Did not strike in my mind.